# Do humans secrete and detect pheremones?

Tags: human-biology, communication, chemical-communication

Many animal species are capapble of secreting and also detecting pheremones from members of the same species, which relay messages and signals such as indicating sexual readiness.

Do humans do the same thing? Are humans capable of communicating in this subconscious fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, humans can secrete and sense pheromones, e.g. female tears dampen male sexual arousal.

[Science 2011, 331(6014), 226-230](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/331/6014/226)

But then on the other hand, a key gene in mouse sex specific behavior (TRPC2) is a pseudogene, i.e. it is inactive, in humans.

[Nature 2007, 448, 1009-1014](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature06089)

If you look at the references in those papers you will probably find a lot more examples.